# Libre office spell check not working, gives "Spell check complete" but does not mark the errors

Tags: debian, spell-checking, libreoffice

I have Libre Office 5.03 on Debian 8_x64. 
I have english interface, but write in Polish.
The spell check does not work. It does not mark obvious errors during writing and when I hit spellcheck icon, it immediately gives "The spellcheck is complete" message ignoring all errors as well.

After googling a bit I did try without success:
- to close Libre office, remove ~/.config/libreoffice directory and restarting the program
- to install language tool

Id did try changing language settings in different configurations, but without any success. 
[language options 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lunJ1.png), [language options 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ2qy.png)

I have run out of ideas how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the text in the document is using the language you expect.  (The setting that your screenshot shows is just the default, and may not reflect the actual document.)  The status at the bottom tells the current language.  If it says English but you want it to check Polish then you need to change the language using `Tools` -> `Language` -> `For all Text`.

This page describes what needs to be installed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72099/how-to-install-a-libreoffice-dictionary-spelling-check-thesaurus.  If you read through it but still cannot get spellchecking to work, then please mention what you installed.